# Custom Member Variables in Admin Notification Email?

Tags: members, plugin, member-details, member-management

- SCROLL FOR NEW EDIT

I understand that EE does not currently have functionality to show you anything beyond the basic member variables in the email notifications (such as username, etc).

I have many custom variables so that when a member registers, they have to enter specific data like contact information.

In order to facilitate the approval process, I NEED the notification email to display the information the user puts into those custom fields.

However, I have been unable to find any combination of plugins and templates that will allow this.

I am currently working with MX Notify and having trouble figuring out if it can actually do this.  Right now I can get it to display the username, screen name and email etc, but I cannot for the life of me get it to display anything else from the user.

I have tried several plugins with no luck.  ANY help is appreciated.

NEW EDIT - 6 JAN 2014

I tried the information from the link in the only answer here so far, and it made no difference.  I still cannot display custom data in an email notification about a member's custom fields.

Is there nobody out there who has successfully done this??

Comment: btw what do you use for user registration? FreeMember?

Comment: Currently using the default Member extension included with EE.

Comment: did you try to use {exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="{member_id}"} ... {/exp:member:custom_profile_data} in email template?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Postmaster](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster) add-on? You should be able to set up a "parcel" to go out when a member registers that could include any custom member or channel fields (see the [Variable Reference](https://www.objectivehtml.com/postmaster/parcels) section in the Postmaster docs).

Comment: Thank you so much, I will go check it out and see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You may of come across this already, but if you haven't, look at http://www.eec.ms/forums/viewthread/117/#1676

Comment: No I hadn't, thank you!  My concerns are: will this work with the most recent version of EE, and then of course, will mucking about with the core then mess me up for future upgrades?  I'm definitely not fond of messing with the core if I don't have to.

Comment: With a little bit of javascript and ajax, you might be able to use this, http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/email-from-template but you might have to disable sending an email to the new user that EE does by default (if that is even possible) so they don't get two emails when they register.

Comment: I'm really hoping there is someone out there that has actually done this who can say with confidence that a particular plugin will work etc.  I know that with some coding, I should be able to get something working, but this is eating up a lot of time when it seems like such a simple task.  Thank you for the suggestion!